# AppStore review and TestFlight beta review at the same time?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Anyone know if you can have a build, lets say version 1.2 in review in AppStore and while it is submitted for review upload a version 1.3 for beta review for TestFlight. Meaning you effectively have two versions in review at the same time (Release review and beta review)?

I want to do this so there will always be a build available for my testers. So once version 1.2 is ready for sale I could enable version 1.3 for external testing.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge No. Its not possible to do the same.